# TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len() : I can't fix this error. I have spendt almost a day but still

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have seen similar cases but most of them are related to strings.
Mine is a pure function. My arrays and functions:

```
L=5, n0=4
n=np.arange(1,n0), x = np.arange(-L, L), t = np.linspace(0,1, 5)
```

```
def eignfun(n,x):
    #n=np.array(n)
    eigf = np.zeros((len(n), len(x)))
    for i in range(len(n)):
        for j in range(len(x)):
            eigf[i,j] = -np.exp(-(x[j] - 2)**2) * np.cos(((n[i] * np.pi)/(2 * L))*(x[j] + L))
    return eigf
```

```
def fnt(n, t):
    fntt = np.zeros((len(n), len(t)))
    dfdt = derivative(f, t, dx=1e-6, n=1)
    d3fdt = derivative(f, t, dx=1e-10, n=3, order=5)
    for i in range(len(n)):
        integral = quad(eignfun, -L, L, args=(n[i],))
        for j in range(len(t)):
            fntt[i, j] = np.exp(-kn[i]*h0) * ((kn[i]*gr*dfdt[j] - d3fdt[j])/kn[i]) * integral[0]
    return fntt
```

The eigfun(n,x) accepts the arrays n and x, and gives the expected result. But the function 
fnt(n,t) does not take the arrays n and t, and it gives the error:

```
eigf = np.zeros((len(n), len(x)))

TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

which is surprisingly connected to the function eignfun(n,x).

Here is for example the result for the function eignfun(n,x):

```
eignfun(x, n)
Out[120]: 
array([[ 3.67879441e-01,  4.28626380e-16, -3.67879441e-01,
        -1.00935848e-17],
       [-1.13680999e-01,  8.09016994e-01,  2.97620720e-01,
        -5.65984368e-03],
       [-2.97620720e-01, -9.51056516e-01, -1.13680999e-01,
         1.07656624e-02],
       [ 2.97620720e-01,  3.09016994e-01, -1.13680999e-01,
        -1.48176631e-02],
       [ 1.13680999e-01,  5.87785252e-01,  2.97620720e-01,
         1.74192077e-02],
       [-3.67879441e-01, -1.00000000e+00, -3.67879441e-01,
        -1.83156389e-02],
       [ 1.13680999e-01,  5.87785252e-01,  2.97620720e-01,
         1.74192077e-02],
       [ 2.97620720e-01,  3.09016994e-01, -1.13680999e-01,
        -1.48176631e-02],
       [-2.97620720e-01, -9.51056516e-01, -1.13680999e-01,
         1.07656624e-02],
       [-1.13680999e-01,  8.09016994e-01,  2.97620720e-01,
        -5.65984368e-03]])
```

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from scipy.misc import derivative
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

L = 5
gr = 10
h0 = 1
x0 = 2
n0 = 5
n=np.arange(1,n0)
x = np.arange(-L, L)
#z = np.linspace(-h0, 0, 10)
t = np.linspace(0,1, 5)
kn = np.array([(i * np.pi) / (2 * L) for i in range(1,len(n)+1)]) # i must start at 1 so i in range(1, len(n)+1)
def xn(n, x):
    xn = np.zeros((len(n), len(x)))
    for i in range(len(n)):
        for j in range(len(x)):
            xn[i, j] = np.cos(kn[i] * (x[j] + L))
    return xn
xnx = xn(n, x)
#print(np.shape(xnx))
def f(t):
    return (t**2)
#f=f(t)
def g(x):
    return -(x - x0)**2
omega_n = np.array([np.sqrt(gr * kn[i] * np.tanh(kn[i] * h0)) for i in range(len(n))])
def eignfun(n,x):
    #n=np.array(n)
    eigf = np.zeros((len(n), len(x)))
    for i in range(len(n)):
        for j in range(len(x)):
            eigf[i,j] = -np.exp(-(x[j] - 2)**2) * np.cos(((n[i] * np.pi)/(2 * L))*(x[j] + L))
    return eigf
def fnt(n, t):
    fntt = np.zeros((len(n), len(t)))
    dfdt = derivative(f, t, dx=1e-6, n=1)
    d3fdt = derivative(f, t, dx=1e-10, n=3, order=5)
    for i in range(len(n)):
        integral = quad(eignfun, -L, L, args=(n[i],))
        for j in range(len(t)):
            fntt[i, j] = np.exp(-kn[i]*h0) * ((kn[i]*gr*dfdt[j] - d3fdt[j])/kn[i]) * integral[0]
    return fntt
eignfun(x, n)
fnt(t, n)
```

Comment: Isn't it obvious that in this call, either `n` or `x` is a number, not a list or array?

Comment: The `fnt()` function does not contain the line `eigf = np.zeros((len(n), len(x)))`, so I'm confused why you think that error is coming from that function...

Comment: Right away, the first line produces a syntax error: `L=5, n0=4`

Comment: I would argue that error is pretty obvious, but still, the `fnt` function is never called in the provided code.

Comment: Show the actual code, and the full error message.  You have paraphrased things too much, resulting in incomplete and syntactically wrong code.

Comment: Ok,am going to post the actual code.

Comment: Reread what `quad` expects the function to do.  It is an 1d integrator.  The function takes one number, and returns one number.  You may pass other variables as the `args` tuple; `quad` just passes those through as is. But the first variable is the integration variable, and will always be **one** float.  `quad` will call the function multiple times with values in the `-L,L` range.

Comment: If a title doesn't tell readers what kind of error "this" error is, it's not doing a good job of summarizing your problem.

Comment: (And all parts of the [MRE] definition are important: if you give up on making your code the shortest thing that solves the problem when run without changes, it's no longer a [MRE], whether you gave up the "minimal" part or the "reproducible" part).

Comment: Am sorry, i couldn't manage it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Feeling exhausted! Hope someone will figure it out. And that will be huge for me

Comment: @hpaulj the point is to iterate x and t over n. Even I tried by switching  the arrays n and x in the function as x is the integration  variable in the (-L, L). But still that doesn't help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ - we don't offer a debugging service; before posting, you are supposed to track down *what* is happening in the code in order to ask a proper question about *why*. For example: where the code says `eigf = np.zeros((len(n), len(x)))` - what do you think will be the values of `n` and `x`? Why should they have those values? **Did you try to check** what the values actually are? Does it make sense to apply `len` to those values? Do you understand what the error message is telling you?

Comment: "which is surprisingly connected to the function eignfun(n,x)" - **why does this surprise you**? When you wrote `eignfun`, it was because you understood that `fnt` would call `quad`, and pass the `eignfun` to it, and that `quad` would then call the passed-in `eignfun` - right?

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `quad(eignfun, -L, L, args=(n[i],))`, exactly what do you expect this to mean? What is your understanding of how `quad` works, and how did you decide to pass these specific arguments?

Comment: And above all of that: **what calculation exactly are you trying to do** with this part of the code? `eignfun` is supposed to take in two arrays and compute a new array, right? What exactly should it mean to integrate that function from -5 to 5?

Answer (score 1):

Test the code with this change:

```
def eignfun(n,x):
    print(n, x)               # show what `quad` passes in
    eigf = np.zeros((len(n), len(x)))
    for i in range(len(n)):
        for j in range(len(x)):
            eigf[i,j] = -np.exp(-(x[j] - 2)**2) * np.cos(((n[i] * np.pi)/(2 * L))*(x[j] + L))
    return eigf
```

Or test it with

```
eignfun(-L, n[0])
```

which should be what `quad` passes to `eignfun` the first time (with `i=0`).

Keep in mind that the `n,x` that `quad` uses are not the global arrays of the same name.

`quad` is roughly  `integral (-L,L) eignfun(u, v) du` (intentionally using different names than your 'x,n,t'.  The integration variable ranges from -L to L.  It is a number, not an array.

Comment: @karl thanks, yes it is my first post, but I have learnt from Stack overflow alot and I will improve all those staffs.

Comment: when I test the function eignfun(n,x) it gives a list like
```
[1 2 3 4] [-5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4]
```
However,  
```eignfun(-L,n[0]) 
```
results with the usual error
```
eigf = np.zeros((len(n), len(x)))

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Comment: maybe `quad` isn't the integrator you want.  Do read it's documentation carefully, and don't make assumptions.

Comment: I think as long as  I have a function of one variable, quad should manage that if the required parameters are passed correctly. Does passing x as an array make sense since quad integrates from -L to L where x is in [-L,L]? What I need is iterate the integral for each n.

Comment: The first argument to your function is chosen by `quad`, and will be **one** float.  It expects back **one** float.  The other arguments may be arrays, since `quad` just passes those through.  But they aren't allowed to change the size of the return value.

Comment: May be I have to play how the eignfun(n,x) should be defined so that it will communicate well with the quad.